# CSS Transition Width div box to expand to the left when mouse hovers over it

Tags: html, css-transitions

[image: Div box to expand when hovering over the button]

I have an interesting problem I'm trying to solve.  I have this donate button that's created using the following the css.

```
#donate-button {
    width: 211px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFBC2F;
    color: #FFF;
    left: 1140px;
    right:1340px;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 0px;
    transition:width 2s;
    transition:left 2s;
    transition:bottom 2s;
}
```

And the css transition effect I want for this is that the donate button's orange background to expand.  It will expand leftwards, towards bottom left, while the top and right frame of the button remains intact in the corner of the browser.

I tried applying the following css transition hover property like so:

```
#donate-button:hover {
    width:33%;
    left:73%;
    bottom: 53%;
}
```

The donate button only does the resizing on the bottom frame, but not the left frame and its width. But I'm suspecting I didn't know how to apply the transition delay and duration times combination so I couldn't really quite get the correct effect...

Can somebody point me to the right direction in how I can achieve this type of effect/animation?  Any ideas?

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
transition:width 2s;
transition:left 2s;
transition:bottom 2s;
```

You are *overwriting* the `transition` property here two times, so that only the last value finally “survives”.

You have to put all three values you want to animate into **one** `transition` property,

```
transition:width 2s, left 2s, bottom 2s;
```

Comment: Okay.  That helps. The left frame and width adjustment are reanimated.  But now that the bottom gets expanded immediately first (without any transition animation), before the first two were animated.  So I must have done something else wrong here.  How my hover should work is that I want the left and width frame gets animated first, then the bottom frame gets animated last in smooth gradual animation.  What do I need to do?

Comment: With transitions you can only start everything that is happening at the same time. If you want several things happening after one another, then you will have to use CSS animations.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  I guess I will have to research the correct CSS animations options I need to make this effect..  unless you have any good recommendations that I could take a look at?

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found the answer.

I should be doing like this.

```
#donate-button {
    height:80px;
    width: 211px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFBC2F;
    color: #FFF;
    left: 1140px;
    right:1340px;
    z-index: 30;
    top: 0px;
    transition:height 2s ease-in, width 2s ease-out, left 2s ease-out, bottom 2s ease-in;
}

#donate-button:hover {
    height:30%;
    width:53%;
    left:77%;
    bottom: 23%;
}
```

I forgot to add the height property.  That's why the height was expanded too quickly when hovering, thus no animation was possible.